# Unity: "Find" can only be called from the main thread, but moving variables to the Start() function causes other errors

Tags: unity, 2d

```
    #pragma strict

 var collided = false;
 var thrust: float;
 var pizza = GameObject.Find("pizza-small").GetComponent.<Rigidbody2D>();


     function Start() {

     }

     //hand + pizza collision detection
     function OnCollisionStay2D(coll: Collision2D) {
         if (coll.gameObject.tag == "Pizza") {
             collided = true;
             Debug.Log("Hand+Pizza");
         }
     }


     function Update() {


     //Input
     if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)) {
         Debug.Log("Up");
         transform.position.y+= 0.2;

         if (collided === true) {
         //Adding force to the pizza
         pizza.velocity = Vector3(0,15,0);
         }
     }
     else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) || Input.GetKey("left")) {
         Debug.Log("Left");
         transform.position.x-= 0.1;        
     }
     else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) || Input.GetKey("right")) {
         Debug.Log("Right");
         transform.position.x+= 0.1;        
     }
     else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S) || Input.GetKey("down")) {
         Debug.Log("Down");
         transform.position.y-= 0.1;        
     }
     else if (transform.position.y > -3.5) {
         transform.position.y-= 0.25;
     }
     else {
         collided = false;
     }



 }
```

Moving the 3 initial variable declarations into Start() removes the "Find can only be called from the main thread" error, but then they cannot be used in the Update() function due to variable scope.

If I declare them initially and then set their values inside of the start function, new errors arise.

```
 var pizza;


 function Start() {

 pizza = GameObject.Find("pizza-small").GetComponent.<Rigidbody2D>();

 }
```

If I do that, then when I use:

```
pizza.velocity = Vector3(0,15,0);
```

It states that velocity is not a member of "object".

I have no idea how to fix this, as the program works with no changes to my initial code, but does still give the error. This could be causing problems, as the rigidbody2D of the "pizza-small" is pulled toward any non-preexisting colliders that I add.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Never mind, I fixed it -

```
 var pizza : Rigidbody2D;

  function Start() {
  pizza = GameObject.Find("pizza-small").GetComponent.<Rigidbody2D>();
  }
```